# Selected data not visually being displayed in Qlikview?

Tags: tableau-api, visualization, qlikview, qliksense, kpi

Before importing this single sheet into Qlikview, I had 2 data sets, one from 2016 Olypmics and the other from 2020 in two different Excel files, I combined the sets of data into one so I could visualize this data in Qlikview.

I have two sets of Gold data since one is from 2016 and the other from the 2020 olympic results.

The problem I am having when opening the spread sheet in Qlikview, it shows the correct data but I want it to display both Gold figures instead of just the 2020 figures, I thought doing it as shown in the image would be sufficient for it to display both gold figures but it's just displaying the one set.

How can I get it to display both for each country specified? I will include my Qlikview setup since it might have relevance to my question.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image: Updated table combined]

Comment: What is your data model? Im i right to presume that both datasets are (kinda) separated - one table for 2016 and one for 2020? If this is the case then ideally you'll have to combine them into one table and have a new field for the year. Then avg(Gold) will return result for both datasets

Comment: Yes I had separate tables but for Qlikview I had to combine them for it to work, I updated my post with a screenshot of the updated table. I don't understand how to connect the two years with the gold values for each data set to where I can visualize it on Qlikview